# Variables combined in one line of indexOf method (Eloquent Javascript)

Tags: javascript, indexof

I felt confused about the following function from [Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html#c_eFskSRBd2j)

```
function hasEvent(event, entry) {
  return entry.events.indexOf(event) != -1;
}
```

What does `entry.events.indexOf(event)` mean?

Comment: `entry.events` is presumably an array. So it searches `event` in that array.

Comment: The paragraph immediately under the code (on the page you linked to) explains the code.

Comment: I know how indexOf works, but it's a little hard to know. Also, I don't know what is the "a given value"...whether it is entry, entry.events or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`entry` is an object with an `events` property (which is probably an array). `events` has the method `indexOf`. You then check the index of `event` in `events`, and compare against -1.

It's not combing variables, just accessing object properties.

Comment: So this means to find out the index number of `events` inside `entry`?

Comment: No, it sees if `entry` is present in the (presumed array) `events`.  If it is, `indexOf()` will return zero or above (the index in the array).  If it is not present, `indexOf()` will return `-1`.  So the whole expression will be `true` if `entry` is in the array of events, or `false` if it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

`event` and `entry` are variables, `events` is a property of the object referenced by the `entry` variable.

Arrays and strings in Javascript provide an `indexOf` method which searches the Array or string referenced for the value and returns its index.

For example:

```
"one two three".indexOf("two"); // 4
```

and

```
[21, 15, 99].indexOf(99); // 2
```

Answer (score 1):

`indexOf()` is a standard method on arrays. Quoting [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

> The `indexOf()` method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

So the `hasEvent()` function is simply checking if the value of `event` exists in the `entry.events` array.

N.B. `indexOf()` is also a standard method on JavaScript String objects. Again quoting [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

> The `indexOf()` method returns the index within the calling String object of the first occurrence of the specified value, starting the search at fromIndex [an optional second parameter]. Returns -1 if the value is not found.

If `typeof entry.events === 'string'` returns true then the `hasEvent()` function will check if the value of `event` exists anywhere in the `entry.events` string.

Comment: Don't you mean the `events` array?  And what if `events` is a string?

Comment: @AlexMcMillan 1) oops, yeah the array name was a typo. Amended in my answer. 2) The originally linked example only concerns arrays but feel free to elaborate.

Comment: There is no mention of arrays in the original question, and that link may not exist in the future.  `indexOf` is the only indicator, and it applies to both arrays and strings.  Nice half-answer tho

Comment: @AlexMcMillan thanks for the feedback. Amended my answer.